# Error connecting to Sphinx via the MySQL protocol

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I'm using gem `'thinking-sphinx', '~> 3.1.1'` in my Rails app. I follow all step from Git hub for install `thinking-sphinx`, but when I search record it give me error

> Error connecting to Sphinx via the MySQL protocol. Error connecting to
>   Sphinx via the MySQL protocol.
>
> Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   '127.0.0.1' (111) - SELECT * FROM `listing_core`, `listing_delta`
>   WHERE MATCH('*product* *1*') AND `community_ids` = 1 AND
>   `sphinx_deleted` = 0 ORDER BY `sort_date` DESC LIMIT 0, 24 OPTION
>   field_weights=(title=10, category=8, description=3); SHOW META

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like the Sphinx daemon isn't running. You'll need to run the `rake ts:start` task to start the daemon.

Comment: How can i write a rails minitest for testing thinking Sphinx. I am getting same error also rake ts:start is not running. Please help